# Getting list of records from foreign keys of another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and am trying to get the entity models from a foreign key of another table.  The code below is how I know to get a list of models, but I don't want the models that have the fk1.  I want the models of those models foreign key references.  I know I can iterate over those models after getting the list and access the foreign key from there, but what is the proper way to grab them from entity at once?

```
List<Entity.Models.myModel> myModels = context.myModels
  .Where(r => r.fk1 == fk1) 
  .ToList();
```

what I want is a list of myModels[i].foreignKey2.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you want to grab the entity and its fk table at the same time you can use 'Include' ie:

List<Entity.Models.myModel> myModels = context.myModels.Where(r => r.foreignKey == foreignKey).Include("NameOfOtherTable").ToList();

Comment: But a given foreign key value references *only one* object (whose primary key value is the same as the given foreign key value) that you could just load with `context.MyReferencedModels.Find(foreignKey);`. I probably misunderstand the question...

Comment: @Slauma I totally messed up my question and you would be right if it was actually what I was trying to say.  My apologies.  I updated the question to reflect my true question.

Comment: I still don't get it. What is `foreignKey2`? I think it would help if you could show the problem with a real example model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

Given an `Order` entity with a reference to a `ShippingType` and a `Customer`...

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ShippingTypeId { get; set; }
    public ShippingType ShippingType { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

...you want to retrieve all customers that have orders with a given shipping type ID. Then the query could look like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.ShippingTypeId == givenShippingTypeId) // your fk1
    .Select(o => o.Customer) // your foreignKey2 ???
    .Distinct() // To eliminate duplicate customers in the result
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need is this:

```
db.myModels.Include("myForeignModel").Where(r => r.name.contains("h")).toList
```

what this will return is a list of models wich name contains 'h' and all these models will have a foreing model loaded for eaxample

```
public class Parent
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int childId {get;set;
    public virtual child child {get;set;}
}

public class child
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name {get;set;}

}
```

now let's say you have a table for parents and another one for children

```
public dbset<parent> parents {get;set;}
public dbset<child> children {get;set;}
```

now what if you want to get the first child name of a parent that is called 'john' you will do this query

```
var db = new mycontext()

var parent = db.parents.include("child").Where(p => p.name == "john").FirstorDefault();

parent.child.name //this will show the child name for the parent called john
```